# MQTT over WebSockets periodically disconnecting

Tags: google-cloud-platform, websocket, mqtt

We have been running eclipse-mosquitto 1.6.10 in Google Cloud Platform for months without issue. We use both MQTT protocol and websockets. We have one Google Cloud TCP load balancer for each protocol - one running on port 443 for MQTT and one running port 9200 for websockets. They provide TLS for both connections. There is only 1 broker which both of the load balancers point to.

Last night at 19:30 BST (UTC +1), the broker started having timeout issues and we were unable to find the root cause. In the end, we spun up a new server with a fresh image and new load balancers. The timeout issues stopped, and regular MQTT connections are now working perfectly. However, websocket connections are now intermittently failing. The browser attempts to connect, and after a delay of ~20 seconds, either connects or fails. Even successful connections are then dropping shortly after - anywhere between 20 seconds and 8 minutes.

We have upped the Linux open file limit and have also tried upgrading to 1.6.14. Rebooting Mosquitto and the entire server doesn't fix the problem but does seem to slightly more likely that connections succeed for a short time.

The server that the broker is running on is not under high load.

Any insights would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: If you suspect/find any indication of a potential GCP specific issue, I would suggest [reporting the issue](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers#trackers-list) with [issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187245&template=0), so that the GCP Support team can take a deeper look, if needed.